# echo 15 random lines of html files

Tags: php

I have to do a php assignment for college.

How would I echo 15 random lines of a html file if there is a movie script text and a image with the same in the same folder?

What I have tried so far:

```
$folder = 'Filmnoir/';
$hitchcock ='Hitchcock/';
$shakespear ='Shakespear/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$file2 = glob ($hitchcock.$filetype);
$file3 = glob ($shakespear.$filetype);
$count = count($files);
$count1 = count($file2);
$count2 = count($file3);
$scripttype ='*.html';
$Scripts = glob($ScriptFilmNoir.$scripttype);
$Scripts=file_get_contents("DoubleIndemnity.html");

if($_POST['radio1']=="0"){
if(($i %1)==0){
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{

    echo '<div class="image2">';
    echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'" />';
    echo '</div>';
    if (condition) {
    include 'DoubleIndemnity.html'; }
    echo '</td></tr>';
}

echo '<div class="Passwordtext">';
echo 'Type in password to view full Script';
echo '</div>';
echo "<label><div class=\"password\"><input type='password' name='code' value='code'/></div></label>";
echo "<form method='POST' action='ca1_result.php'>";
echo "<div class=\"SubmitIt\"><input type='submit' name='submitScript' value='Submit Password'/></div>";
echo '</form>';
}
}
if($_POST['radio1']=="1"){
echo '<div class="Sorrytext">';
echo 'We apologize. No script available for this movie.';
echo '</div>';
}
if($_POST['radio1']=="2"){
echo '<div class="Sorrytext">';
echo 'We apologize. No script available for this movie.';
echo '</div>';
}
```

I want to achieve that when there is an image (e.g `DoubleIndemnity.png`) and movie script (e.g `DoubleIndemnity.html`) in the same folder that I get 15 random lines of the movie script text plus the image. Could I use the `glob` function and when yes how would I achieve that?

Can I ask another thing? When I submit the password how to I get then the full movie script?

I tried:

```
foreach($files as $file2) {
if($_POST['submitPassword']){
if($file2 === '.' OR $file2 === '..' OR $file2 === 'thumbs.db' OR !is_dir($folder.'/'.$file2)) {continue;}
    if(file_exists($folder.'/'.$file2.'/doubleindemnity.gif') AND file_exists($folder.'/'.$file2.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm')) {
        echo '<div class="Container">';
        echo "<div class='image2'><img src='$folder/$file/doubleindemnity.gif'>";
        $lines4 = file($folder.'/'.$file2.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm');
         $count = count($lines4);
        for($a = 0;$a < $count;$a++) {
        echo substr($lines4[$a],strlen($folder),strpos($lines4[$a], '.')-strlen($folder));
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
      echo "</div>";
}
}
?>
```

With that code I just get a couple of lines from the html file. I don't want that. I want the full text. And how can I use the string replace function to get rid of the code and just receive the text from the paragraphs?

Cheers:)

Comment: Do you have to use the glob function? Is there a particular reason you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will loop trough folders in a pre-defined folder (eg: /movies). It will look if whatever is inside is a folder, and if that folder has 2 files: image.png and lines.html. If it has those two files, it'll first place the image, then it'll read the HTML file, and writing down 15 random lines from that file.

```
<?php
$folder = "movies";
$files = scandir($folder);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file === '.' OR $file === '..' OR $file === 'thumbs.db' OR !is_dir($folder.'/'.$file)) {continue;}
    if(file_exists($folder.'/'.$file.'/image.png') AND file_exists($folder.'/'.$file.'/lines.html')) {
        echo "<div class='image2'><img src='$folder/$file/image.png'>";
        $lines = file($folder.'/'.$file.'/lines.html');
        for($x = 1;$x<=15;$x++) {
            echo $lines[rand(0, count($lines)-1)]."<br>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @UserSC If this is the answer you're looking for, mark this as accepted answer so it won't stay 'unsolved'  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Loops through files in `$directory` and then outputs 15 random lines into a html variable and if the image exists it adds it to the image html variable. If they are both added it returns the result. (untested but should work)

```
<?php
//I dont know where you have got some of these variables from
$directory = "Filmnoir";
$ScriptFilmNoir = "DoubleIndemnity";
$scripttype ='html';
$supportedImages = Array("png", "jpg", "jpeg");
$html = "";
$imagehtml = "";
$allFiles = scandir($folder);
$imageFound = 0;
$htmlFound = 0;

foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file === '.' || $file === '..' || $file === 'thumbs.db' || is_dir($file)) {
        continue;
    }
    $nameWithoutExtension = substr($file, 0 , (strrpos($file, ".")));
    $fileExtension = $id = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);
    if($nameWithoutExtension == $ScriptFilmNoir){
        if($fileExtension == $scripttype){
            $htmlFound = 1;
            $lines = file($directory . "/" . $ScriptFilmNoir . "." . $scripttype);//file in to an array         
            $range = range(1, count($lines));
            $range = array_flip($range);
            $range = array_rand($range, 15);

            foreach($range as $line){
                $html .= $lines[$value] . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }elseif(in_array ( $fileExtension , $supportedImages)){
            $imageFound = 1;
            $imagehtml = "<img src='{$directory}/{$ScriptFilmNoir}.{$fileExtension}' /><br />";
        }
    }
}
if($imageFound == 1 && $htmlFound == 1){
    echo $imagehtml . $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what owen is looking for is a random extract of 15 lines rather than 15 random lines.

Using @ThijmenDF's example, just change

```
for($x = 1;$x<=15;$x++) {
    echo $lines[rand(0, count($lines)-1)]."<br>";
}
```

to

```
$random = rand(0, count($lines)-1);
for($x = 1;$x<=15;$x++) {
    echo $lines[$random + $x]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Cheers stranger that I may know:) But it is no help. Keeps coming the same. I edit my whole code at the moment anyway. Will be glad when it is over. Thanks:)